# WebSockets plus RESTful interface, how to write DRY code in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, dry

My Node.js application provides **both WebSockets and RESTful** interface. I wrote a little replacement for `Backbone.synch` to use with Socket.IO as transport.

**DRY problem**: callbacks executed upon client event contains almost the same logic as callbacks for RESTul paths. An example mapping between events and data emitted by the client, and the corresponding action:

```
+----------------+---------------------------------+--------------------+
| event emitted  | data emitted                    | RESTful URL        |
+----------------+---------------------------------+--------------------+
|     read:users | empty string                    |  GET /users        |
|     read:users | id of the model                 |  GET /users/:id    |
|   create:users | full model as JSON              |  POST /users       |
|  destroy:users | id of the model                 |  DELETE /users/:id |
|   update:users | full model as JSON (with id)    |  PUT /users/:id    |
|    patch:users | partial model as JSON (with id) |  PUT /users/:id    |
+----------------+---------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Example (99% of duplicated logic/code):

```js
var UserModel = require('./models/user'); // Mongoose model

// Express path
app.get('/users/:id?', function (req, res)) {
    var query = !id ? {} : { _id: id };

    UserModel.find(query, function (err, doc) {
        return err ? res.send(404, null) : res.send(200, doc);
    });
};

// SocketIO listening to the read:users event
socket.on('read:users', function(id, cb) {
    var query = !id ? {} : { _id: id }

    UserModel.find(query, function (err, doc) {
        return err ? cb(err.message, null) : cb(null, doc);
    });
});
```

Because I'm playing with Node.JS and event programming (and JavaScript) for a few days, I'm looking for a good advice of how design a "controller", like a general purpose object that can handle the duplicated code easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to mix the logic of those two functions, then the way that your client side code passes the arguments to your `socket.on` callback function will have to be changed. You can approach it with the current set up like this:

```
var veryGenericCallback = function(p1, p2) {
   // Note: Not sure what to name the arguments because they are wildly different
   // in your two different cases.

   var query = typeof p1 === "object" : {} : { _id: p1 };

   UserModel.find(query, function (err, doc) {
     var result;

     if (typeof p2 === "function") {
        return err ? p2(err.message, null) : p2(null, doc);
     } else {
        return err ? p2.send(404, null) : p2.send(200, dox);
     }

   });

}
```

But as you can see, at some point you will still have to repeat the logic that you are trying to avoid. However, if your `socket` client code that emits the event passed in an object that had an "id" property on the first argument, and passed an object with a `send` function for your second argument, you could reduce it to this:

```
var veryGenericCallback = function(info, action) {

   var query = info.id ? { _id: info.id } : {};

   UserModel.find(query, function (err, doc) {

     return err ? action.send(404, null) : action.send(200, doc);

   });

}
```

However in this case you would need to change the code on your server side to handle whatever it is your pseudo-send method does (and you would need to define that in the first place somewhere the client has access to it). This also severely restricts what you can do in your callbacks, as any function you want to call on an actual Request/Response object will have to be mimicked in your socket client code. This muddles the readability and extensiblity of your code in my opinion, but it certainly can be achieved.

Comment: While I appreciate your effort, I have to say that I disagree with your answer. I know what modules are, but your solution is simply moving both callbacks in a separate module. Something to do for sure, but my question was about the logic of combining them (with problems related to parameters). Thanks anyways!

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrate that with your current set up, there isn't a way to get around the logic duplication problem. However, if you adjusted your client code that emits the socket event to pass in an object with similar functions/properties to what is received in the app.get() call (Request and Response objects), then you can reduce the code repetition. However, in my personal opinion, I feel that this is bad practice as you are really limiting the things you can do with this function (without adding more complex code visible to your client side socket info).